# Scanner works in laptop, not in desktop

Tags: linux-mint, usb, scanner

I have an Epson Perfection 660 flatbed scanner that works on my laptop. This is what appears in `/var/log/syslog` when I plug it in:

```
Dec 18 15:43:57 lap kernel: [   31.868278] usb 6-2: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
Dec 18 15:43:57 lap kernel: [   32.033506] usb 6-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04b8, idProduct=0114
Dec 18 15:43:57 lap kernel: [   32.033514] usb 6-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Dec 18 15:43:57 lap kernel: [   32.033519] usb 6-2: Product: EPSON Scanner
Dec 18 15:43:57 lap kernel: [   32.033524] usb 6-2: Manufacturer: EPSON
```

Now I want to use that scanner in my desktop computer. I followed the same instructions, but it does not work. The problem is that it's not recognized as a valid USB device. It does not appear on `lsusb`, and this is what shows in syslog:

```
Dec 18 15:31:34 desktop kernel: [  390.193219] usb 3-14: new full-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
Dec 18 15:31:39 desktop kernel: [  395.213900] usb 3-14: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
Dec 18 15:31:39 desktop kernel: [  395.213902] usb 3-14: can't read configurations, error -110
Dec 18 15:31:39 desktop kernel: [  395.325902] usb 3-14: new full-speed USB device number 19 using xhci_hcd
Dec 18 15:31:44 desktop kernel: [  400.346570] usb 3-14: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
Dec 18 15:31:44 desktop kernel: [  400.346572] usb 3-14: can't read configurations, error -110
Dec 18 15:31:45 desktop kernel: [  400.458648] usb 3-14: new full-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
Dec 18 15:31:50 desktop kernel: [  405.479280] usb 3-14: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
Dec 18 15:31:50 desktop kernel: [  405.479282] usb 3-14: can't read configurations, error -110
Dec 18 15:31:50 desktop kernel: [  405.591352] usb 3-14: new full-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
Dec 18 15:31:55 desktop kernel: [  410.611960] usb 3-14: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
Dec 18 15:31:55 desktop kernel: [  410.611962] usb 3-14: can't read configurations, error -110
Dec 18 15:31:55 desktop kernel: [  410.611973] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 14
```

At first sight, looks like the laptop uses UHCI, whereas the desktop uses XHCI. Both systems use Linux Mint 16, kernel 3.11.0-12 x86_64. The behavior is the same regardless of the usb port used.

What can I do?

Comment: Does the desktop pc BIOS allow for setting different USB modes?

Comment: I have the exact same problem with the exact same scanner (but I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu w/Linux 3.13.0-45). Sometimes instead of error -110 the logs show the device as being identified correctly, but immediately followed by "string descriptor 0 read error: -32". On very rare occasions it just works (no errors when plugged in, identified correctly and scanning works). [-110 apparently means not enough power](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13661508/717501), which is doubly funny because the damn thing has its own power source, and surely a desktop PSU has more power than a laptop...